# Did Edna Mode design the superhero costumes with capes?

Tags: the-incredibles

In The Incredibles, Edna Mode has a strong stance against capes on superheroes because of the multiple untimely deaths directly caused by capes.

What I can't seem to figure out is if Edna actually designed capes into the costumes and learned from her mistakes, or if that was a mistake made by others that she wanted to avoid.

I ask this because I've run across several people looking into her line:

> Edna: "I never look back, dahling! It distracts from the now."

as a kind of joke or commentary about how headstrong she is for designing suits after her mistakes effectively killed at least six heroes.

Comment: Two of the capes in question, if you look at the quote, were in action in the late 50's.  I doubt she made those ones.

Comment: Possible dupe of [What prompted Edna Mode's “no capes” rule?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18091/what-prompted-edna-modes-no-capes-rule).

Comment: @Valorum: Seeing as nobody at that question came up with CHEESE's comment about the timelines not matching (while CHEESE came up with it in ~15 minutes), I'm skeptical of your dupe-vote.  I do not think that the answer to that question is a good answer to *this* question.

Comment: @Kevin - I've not voted as a dupe. I've merely highlighted it as a possible (future?) dupe since any sort of backstory to Edna would likely answer the other question as well.

Comment: @CHEESE - The Incredibles seems to be set quite early in the new millennium. Edna's age isn't defined, but she could easily be in her 60s. If Edna started designing superhero suits in her late teens, she could have been responsible for the suits in question, or at least apprenticed to whoever designed them.

Comment: @CHEESE I'd dispute the late 50s timeline. It would seem to be the same timeline as 'the past' for Mr Incredible. Which is highly stylised and non specific.

Comment: Since Edna Mode was inspired by/based on Edith Head, who designed costumes for films for just over 50 years, there's no reason Edna couldn't have been designing suits in the fifties, especially if you accept the theory that The Incredibles took place during the seventies.

Comment: @JeremyFrench: Edna names the years precisely.  They are in the late 50's.  Now, if you want to dispute when the "present" is, that might work, but the movie doesn't look very 90's-or-earlier to me.

Comment: @CHEESE - A bit of research reveals that The Incredibles is actually set in 1962, at least according to Bob's newspaper in the opening sequence

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Possibly.

The [Incredibles: Essential Guide](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2125677.The_Incredibles_Essential_Guide) contains the following information about Edna Mode:

> **Cape catastrophes**
>
> *A cape might seem like an accessory no Super could do without, but in reality, they are a real safety hazard. When you look at the number of Supers who have had cape-related mishaps, it's no wonder E has vowed **never to make a cape again....***

This strongly implies that she made them *at least once* in the past. Whether it was for those specific (and unfortunate) heroes isn't clear, but it's at least possible that she designed some/all of the suits we see in the flashback sequence.